# How to use Movesense SendUartData

Tags: movesense

BleController.hpp has SendUartData. Should this work with 1.1.0? I can call send_ble_hr_measurement and get OnUartData notifications ok but not sure how to call SendUartData instead of send_ble_hr_measurement in ble_std_services examples.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunally BleController::SendUartData() has bug and not working properly in 1.1.0. This bug is corrected in revision 1.2.0 which is just coming, but this method is deleted and replaced by public function void send_ble_nus_data(uint8_t * p_data, uint16_t length);

Comment: Thank you for this information. Now with 1.2.0 send_ble_nus_data is working. This enables streaming into e.g. PC